# CORS error when accessing API Gateway with Cognito authentication from React application

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway-v2

I am using API gateway with cognito for Authorize a POST method endpoint. if I am running it through Postman (JSON) it works great. BUT when I am running through a react app in CHROME I get Access to `XMLHttpRequest` at 'https://wjkgn56pb8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Details over my API gateway API

1. POST request with cognito authorizaer with expect a Authorization header
2. The post request has lambda proxy that return the following header:

   > "headers": 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':  'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,X-Amz-Security-Token,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Requested-With,Accept',   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', 'X-Requested-With':'*'
3. OPTIONS method wihtout cognito authorizer
4. I enable CORS on the endpoint.

result:

1. without cognito on the POST it works -> i get content into my react app
2. the moment I add cognito authIi get CORS error
3. the part of react code I am running for this is:

   ```
   async function testClick() {
       try {
           const data = {
               clientId: user.userId,
           };
          const config = {
               headers: {
                   Authorization: user.token,
               },
          };
          const res = await axios.post(
              "https://wjkgn56pb8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test",
              data,
              config
          );
          const messageData = res.data;
          console.log(messageData);
     } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
       } }
   ```

I don't have any idea.

Comment: Yes it works in Postman. Because postman is not a browser and doesn't care about CORS. `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':''`  you need a value for the header ...